# Therapeutic dose as safe antioxidant, melatonin and diabetes

Tags: diabetes, melatonin, antioxidant

This question is not about sleep, but really about the antioxidant benefits of melatonin down to the mitochondrial level. e.g.  https://www.hindawi.com/journals/ijad/2011/326320/ , http://www.mdpi.com/1420-3049/23/3/530/htm  Specifically how might melatonin help the diabetic?  It seems like a good agent. Crosses the blood brain barrier. Inexpensive. But it may raise blood sugar. Here is an article that touches on the potential risks: https://blog.humanos.me/research-reveals-an-odd-connection-between-melatonin-and-type-2-diabetes/

If anyone is aware of any (further) studies etc. on this subject I would appreciate knowing about them:  use of melatonin in diabetes, risks and benefits.

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. You ask how might melatonin help diabetics and then go on to say pre-diabetics shouldn't take it at all.

Comment: I realize I am speaking in too broad of terms. In other words, a doctor may say --- consider it on a case by case basis because it is easy enough to monitor the blood sugar etc. on any patient whether diabetic or not. I removed the portion on pre-diabetics.

Comment: Seems like a not really bad question. But an answer might have to start at a more fundamental level than melatonin, namely at antioxidant in general, then work up from there. Looks therefore a bit broad (not too, though). Without having researched this: "The one study" nailing this seems not very likely to exist? Can you confirm that? Where have you searched for this further?

Comment: @LangLangC Here is a study I found. I am in the process of moving my residence at the moment so I have not had much time to devote to it. Study Shows Melatonin Improves Sleep and A1c Levels https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.endocrineweb.com/amp/7589 at 5 months nightly usage.